# Mostrar solo imágenes de la entrada. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, div

Tengo dos divs en una plantilla dentro del single.php y me gustaría mostrar SOLO IMÁGENES de un lado y del otro SOLO TEXTO. Aguien podría ayudarme con esto? Desde ya muchísimas gracias!

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <div class="container details" id="single">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="margin-gutter-bottom">
                    AQUI DEBEN IR LAS IMÁGENES CARGADAS DEL POST
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="margin-gutter-bottom">
                    <?php 
                        the_content;
                    ?>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

para eso está la función `get_children()`

```
<?php
$images =& get_children( array (
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));

if ( empty($images) ) {
} else {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );
    }
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/